# Math.hを使用できない環境でのべき乗計算

Tags: c

お疲れ様です。
C環境で、ガンマ補正関連の画質処理を作成しているのですが、
速度をなるべく早くするということでMath.hを禁止され、
どのようにべき乗計算をするか分からない状態であり、
もしこうして解決したなどの経験がございましたらご教授ください。

**【実行したいこと】**
ガンマ2.2などの画質変換用のLutテーブル作成

**【Math.hがあれば実装していたであろう内容】**
①ガンマ2.2の画像のガンマを外す
    ＝(Y / Y最大値) ^ (2.2)
②ガンマ2.2に再度なおす
    ＝(①の結果) ^ (1.0 / 2.2) * Y最大値
    //// ＝(Y) ^ (1.0 / 2.2) * Y最大値 **//間違い**

※このべき乗をpowでやる予定でした。

---

<追記>
・YおよびYの最大値は整数になります。10bit 0-1023になります。
・ガンマ値は固定値で、ガンマ2.2、ガンマ1.8、ガンマ2.6‌​で変換をかける予定です。
・「速度 > 精度」の優先順位になっています。
・②の式が間違っていたので修正いたしました。
　①と②は基本ワンセットになっていると思ってください。(片方だけ実行することはない)

以上、よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: ヘッダファイルの使用を禁止というより、数学関数ライブラリの使用を禁止(リンクしない)という事でしょうか？

Comment: `Y`および`Y最大値`の型は整数でしょうか、実数でしょうか？

Comment: metropolisさん　数学関数ライブラリの使用を禁止ということです。時間がかかる処理は一切禁止。自前で早く計算できるならOKという感じです。私は理解できてませんがテイラー定理などを使って出せるなら処理はそこまで増えないという話をされたことはありますが、そういうのはOK？だと思います

Comment: sayuriさん YおよびYの最大値は整数になります。10bit 0-1023になります

Comment: 2.2は決め打ちで良いのでしょうか

Comment: 私も「ガンマ2.2**など**」という記述が気になりました。

Comment: packet0さん、sayuriさん  ご返事いただきありがとうございます。ご連絡が遅くなりまことに申し訳ございません。ガンマ2.2、ガンマ1.8、ガンマ.26で変換をかける予定です。可変というほどではありませんが、上記三つが固定値で入る予定です。

Comment: 追加情報はコメントによる返信ではなく質問本文を更新・追記してください。ガンマが固定値ということであればLUTを事前構築することは可能に思います。１点気になるのは、ガンマ変換・逆変換を行った場合に整数演算で十分な精度を得られるのかどうかです。

Comment: ありがとうございます。本文に追記をいたしました。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 速度をなるべく早くするということでMath.hを禁止され、どのようにべき乗計算をするか分からない

質問の意図（というよりも質問者さんが受けた指示内容）がようやくわかりました。
「`<math.h>`の関数を使わずLookup tableを構築する」ではなくて「Lookup tableを使用することで`<math.h>`の関数を使わず済む」ではないでしょうか。そして予めLUT; Lookup tableを作ってソースコードに埋め込むのではないでしょうか。

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>

const int ymax = 1023;
const double gamma = 2.2;
int encode(int y) {
    return (int)round(ymax * pow((double)y / ymax, 1 / gamma));

}
int decode(int y) {
    return (int)round(ymax * pow((double)y / ymax, gamma));
}

#define GENERATE(FUNC)  do {                    \
    printf("int " #FUNC "(int y) {\n");         \
    printf("    static const int lut[] = { ");  \
    for (int y = 0; y <= ymax; y++)             \
    printf("%d, ", FUNC(y));                    \
    printf("};\n");                             \
    printf("    return lut[y];\n");             \
    printf("};\n");                             \
    } while(0)

int main(){
    GENERATE(encode);
    GENERATE(decode);
    return 0;
}
```

を実行して得られる

```
int encode(int y) {
    static const int lut[] = { 0, 44, 60, 72, 82, 91, 99, 106, 113, 119, 125, 130, 136, 141, 145, 150, 155, 159, 163, 167, 171, 175, 179, 182, 186, 189, 193, 196, 199, 203, 206, 209, 212, 215, 218, 221, 223, 226, 229, 232, 234, 237, 240, 242, 245, 247, 250, 252, 255, 257, 259, 262, 264, 266, 269, 271, 273, 275, 278, 280, 282, 284, 286, 288, 290, 292, 294, 296, 298, 300, 302, 304, 306, 308, 310, 312, 314, 316, 318, 319, 321, 323, 325, 327, 328, 330, 332, 334, 335, 337, 339, 341, 342, 344, 346, 347, 349, 351, 352, 354, 356, 357, 359, 360, 362, 363, 365, 367, 368, 370, 371, 373, 374, 376, 377, 379, 380, 382, 383, 385, 386, 388, 389, 391, 392, 393, 395, 396, 398, 399, 401, 402, 403, 405, 406, 407, 409, 410, 412, 413, 414, 416, 417, 418, 420, 421, 422, 424, 425, 426, 427, 429, 430, 431, 433, 434, 435, 436, 438, 439, 440, 441, 443, 444, 445, 446, 448, 449, 450, 451, 452, 454, 455, 456, 457, 458, 460, 461, 462, 463, 464, 466, 467, 468, 469, 470, 471, 473, 474, 475, 476, 477, 478, 479, 480, 482, 483, 484, 485, 486, 487, 488, 489, 490, 492, 493, 494, 495, 496, 497, 498, 499, 500, 501, 502, 503, 505, 506, 507, 508, 509, 510, 511, 512, 513, 514, 515, 516, 517, 518, 519, 520, 521, 522, 523, 524, 525, 526, 527, 528, 529, 530, 531, 532, 533, 534, 535, 536, 537, 538, 539, 540, 541, 542, 543, 544, 545, 546, 547, 548, 549, 550, 551, 552, 553, 554, 555, 556, 556, 557, 558, 559, 560, 561, 562, 563, 564, 565, 566, 567, 568, 569, 570, 570, 571, 572, 573, 574, 575, 576, 577, 578, 579, 580, 580, 581, 582, 583, 584, 585, 586, 587, 588, 588, 589, 590, 591, 592, 593, 594, 595, 595, 596, 597, 598, 599, 600, 601, 601, 602, 603, 604, 605, 606, 607, 607, 608, 609, 610, 611, 612, 613, 613, 614, 615, 616, 617, 618, 618, 619, 620, 621, 622, 623, 623, 624, 625, 626, 627, 627, 628, 629, 630, 631, 632, 632, 633, 634, 635, 636, 636, 637, 638, 639, 640, 640, 641, 642, 643, 644, 644, 645, 646, 647, 647, 648, 649, 650, 651, 651, 652, 653, 654, 655, 655, 656, 657, 658, 658, 659, 660, 661, 661, 662, 663, 664, 665, 665, 666, 667, 668, 668, 669, 670, 671, 671, 672, 673, 674, 674, 675, 676, 677, 677, 678, 679, 680, 680, 681, 682, 683, 683, 684, 685, 686, 686, 687, 688, 688, 689, 690, 691, 691, 692, 693, 694, 694, 695, 696, 696, 697, 698, 699, 699, 700, 701, 701, 702, 703, 704, 704, 705, 706, 706, 707, 708, 709, 709, 710, 711, 711, 712, 713, 713, 714, 715, 716, 716, 717, 718, 718, 719, 720, 720, 721, 722, 723, 723, 724, 725, 725, 726, 727, 727, 728, 729, 729, 730, 731, 731, 732, 733, 733, 734, 735, 735, 736, 737, 738, 738, 739, 740, 740, 741, 742, 742, 743, 744, 744, 745, 746, 746, 747, 748, 748, 749, 750, 750, 751, 751, 752, 753, 753, 754, 755, 755, 756, 757, 757, 758, 759, 759, 760, 761, 761, 762, 763, 763, 764, 765, 765, 766, 766, 767, 768, 768, 769, 770, 770, 771, 772, 772, 773, 773, 774, 775, 775, 776, 777, 777, 778, 779, 779, 780, 780, 781, 782, 782, 783, 784, 784, 785, 785, 786, 787, 787, 788, 789, 789, 790, 790, 791, 792, 792, 793, 794, 794, 795, 795, 796, 797, 797, 798, 798, 799, 800, 800, 801, 801, 802, 803, 803, 804, 805, 805, 806, 806, 807, 808, 808, 809, 809, 810, 811, 811, 812, 812, 813, 814, 814, 815, 815, 816, 817, 817, 818, 818, 819, 820, 820, 821, 821, 822, 822, 823, 824, 824, 825, 825, 826, 827, 827, 828, 828, 829, 830, 830, 831, 831, 832, 832, 833, 834, 834, 835, 835, 836, 836, 837, 838, 838, 839, 839, 840, 841, 841, 842, 842, 843, 843, 844, 845, 845, 846, 846, 847, 847, 848, 849, 849, 850, 850, 851, 851, 852, 853, 853, 854, 854, 855, 855, 856, 856, 857, 858, 858, 859, 859, 860, 860, 861, 862, 862, 863, 863, 864, 864, 865, 865, 866, 867, 867, 868, 868, 869, 869, 870, 870, 871, 871, 872, 873, 873, 874, 874, 875, 875, 876, 876, 877, 878, 878, 879, 879, 880, 880, 881, 881, 882, 882, 883, 884, 884, 885, 885, 886, 886, 887, 887, 888, 888, 889, 889, 890, 891, 891, 892, 892, 893, 893, 894, 894, 895, 895, 896, 896, 897, 897, 898, 899, 899, 900, 900, 901, 901, 902, 902, 903, 903, 904, 904, 905, 905, 906, 906, 907, 908, 908, 909, 909, 910, 910, 911, 911, 912, 912, 913, 913, 914, 914, 915, 915, 916, 916, 917, 917, 918, 918, 919, 919, 920, 921, 921, 922, 922, 923, 923, 924, 924, 925, 925, 926, 926, 927, 927, 928, 928, 929, 929, 930, 930, 931, 931, 932, 932, 933, 933, 934, 934, 935, 935, 936, 936, 937, 937, 938, 938, 939, 939, 940, 940, 941, 941, 942, 942, 943, 943, 944, 944, 945, 945, 946, 946, 947, 947, 948, 948, 949, 949, 950, 950, 951, 951, 952, 952, 953, 953, 954, 954, 955, 955, 956, 956, 957, 957, 958, 958, 959, 959, 960, 960, 961, 961, 962, 962, 963, 963, 964, 964, 965, 965, 966, 966, 967, 967, 968, 968, 969, 969, 970, 970, 970, 971, 971, 972, 972, 973, 973, 974, 974, 975, 975, 976, 976, 977, 977, 978, 978, 979, 979, 980, 980, 981, 981, 982, 982, 982, 983, 983, 984, 984, 985, 985, 986, 986, 987, 987, 988, 988, 989, 989, 990, 990, 991, 991, 992, 992, 992, 993, 993, 994, 994, 995, 995, 996, 996, 997, 997, 998, 998, 999, 999, 999, 1000, 1000, 1001, 1001, 1002, 1002, 1003, 1003, 1004, 1004, 1005, 1005, 1006, 1006, 1006, 1007, 1007, 1008, 1008, 1009, 1009, 1010, 1010, 1011, 1011, 1012, 1012, 1012, 1013, 1013, 1014, 1014, 1015, 1015, 1016, 1016, 1017, 1017, 1018, 1018, 1018, 1019, 1019, 1020, 1020, 1021, 1021, 1022, 1022, 1023, 1023, };
    return lut[y];
};
int decode(int y) {
    static const int lut[] = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 14, 14, 14, 14, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 16, 16, 16, 16, 17, 17, 17, 17, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 19, 19, 19, 19, 20, 20, 20, 21, 21, 21, 21, 22, 22, 22, 22, 23, 23, 23, 23, 24, 24, 24, 25, 25, 25, 25, 26, 26, 26, 27, 27, 27, 28, 28, 28, 29, 29, 29, 29, 30, 30, 30, 31, 31, 31, 32, 32, 32, 33, 33, 33, 34, 34, 34, 35, 35, 35, 36, 36, 37, 37, 37, 38, 38, 38, 39, 39, 39, 40, 40, 41, 41, 41, 42, 42, 43, 43, 43, 44, 44, 44, 45, 45, 46, 46, 46, 47, 47, 48, 48, 49, 49, 49, 50, 50, 51, 51, 52, 52, 52, 53, 53, 54, 54, 55, 55, 55, 56, 56, 57, 57, 58, 58, 59, 59, 60, 60, 61, 61, 61, 62, 62, 63, 63, 64, 64, 65, 65, 66, 66, 67, 67, 68, 68, 69, 69, 70, 70, 71, 71, 72, 72, 73, 73, 74, 75, 75, 76, 76, 77, 77, 78, 78, 79, 79, 80, 80, 81, 82, 82, 83, 83, 84, 84, 85, 85, 86, 87, 87, 88, 88, 89, 89, 90, 91, 91, 92, 92, 93, 94, 94, 95, 95, 96, 97, 97, 98, 98, 99, 100, 100, 101, 102, 102, 103, 103, 104, 105, 105, 106, 107, 107, 108, 109, 109, 110, 110, 111, 112, 112, 113, 114, 114, 115, 116, 116, 117, 118, 118, 119, 120, 121, 121, 122, 123, 123, 124, 125, 125, 126, 127, 127, 128, 129, 130, 130, 131, 132, 132, 133, 134, 135, 135, 136, 137, 138, 138, 139, 140, 141, 141, 142, 143, 144, 144, 145, 146, 147, 147, 148, 149, 150, 150, 151, 152, 153, 154, 154, 155, 156, 157, 157, 158, 159, 160, 161, 161, 162, 163, 164, 165, 166, 166, 167, 168, 169, 170, 170, 171, 172, 173, 174, 175, 175, 176, 177, 178, 179, 180, 181, 181, 182, 183, 184, 185, 186, 187, 187, 188, 189, 190, 191, 192, 193, 194, 194, 195, 196, 197, 198, 199, 200, 201, 202, 203, 203, 204, 205, 206, 207, 208, 209, 210, 211, 212, 213, 214, 215, 216, 216, 217, 218, 219, 220, 221, 222, 223, 224, 225, 226, 227, 228, 229, 230, 231, 232, 233, 234, 235, 236, 237, 238, 239, 240, 241, 242, 243, 244, 245, 246, 247, 248, 249, 250, 251, 252, 253, 254, 255, 256, 257, 258, 259, 260, 261, 262, 263, 264, 265, 266, 267, 269, 270, 271, 272, 273, 274, 275, 276, 277, 278, 279, 280, 281, 283, 284, 285, 286, 287, 288, 289, 290, 291, 292, 294, 295, 296, 297, 298, 299, 300, 301, 303, 304, 305, 306, 307, 308, 309, 311, 312, 313, 314, 315, 316, 317, 319, 320, 321, 322, 323, 324, 326, 327, 328, 329, 330, 332, 333, 334, 335, 336, 338, 339, 340, 341, 342, 344, 345, 346, 347, 348, 350, 351, 352, 353, 355, 356, 357, 358, 360, 361, 362, 363, 365, 366, 367, 368, 370, 371, 372, 373, 375, 376, 377, 378, 380, 381, 382, 384, 385, 386, 387, 389, 390, 391, 393, 394, 395, 397, 398, 399, 401, 402, 403, 405, 406, 407, 409, 410, 411, 413, 414, 415, 417, 418, 419, 421, 422, 423, 425, 426, 427, 429, 430, 432, 433, 434, 436, 437, 438, 440, 441, 443, 444, 445, 447, 448, 450, 451, 452, 454, 455, 457, 458, 459, 461, 462, 464, 465, 467, 468, 469, 471, 472, 474, 475, 477, 478, 480, 481, 483, 484, 485, 487, 488, 490, 491, 493, 494, 496, 497, 499, 500, 502, 503, 505, 506, 508, 509, 511, 512, 514, 515, 517, 518, 520, 521, 523, 524, 526, 527, 529, 530, 532, 534, 535, 537, 538, 540, 541, 543, 544, 546, 548, 549, 551, 552, 554, 555, 557, 559, 560, 562, 563, 565, 567, 568, 570, 571, 573, 575, 576, 578, 579, 581, 583, 584, 586, 587, 589, 591, 592, 594, 596, 597, 599, 601, 602, 604, 605, 607, 609, 610, 612, 614, 615, 617, 619, 620, 622, 624, 625, 627, 629, 631, 632, 634, 636, 637, 639, 641, 642, 644, 646, 648, 649, 651, 653, 654, 656, 658, 660, 661, 663, 665, 667, 668, 670, 672, 674, 675, 677, 679, 681, 682, 684, 686, 688, 689, 691, 693, 695, 697, 698, 700, 702, 704, 705, 707, 709, 711, 713, 714, 716, 718, 720, 722, 724, 725, 727, 729, 731, 733, 735, 736, 738, 740, 742, 744, 746, 747, 749, 751, 753, 755, 757, 759, 760, 762, 764, 766, 768, 770, 772, 774, 776, 777, 779, 781, 783, 785, 787, 789, 791, 793, 795, 796, 798, 800, 802, 804, 806, 808, 810, 812, 814, 816, 818, 820, 822, 824, 826, 828, 829, 831, 833, 835, 837, 839, 841, 843, 845, 847, 849, 851, 853, 855, 857, 859, 861, 863, 865, 867, 869, 871, 873, 875, 877, 879, 881, 883, 885, 887, 889, 892, 894, 896, 898, 900, 902, 904, 906, 908, 910, 912, 914, 916, 918, 920, 922, 925, 927, 929, 931, 933, 935, 937, 939, 941, 943, 945, 948, 950, 952, 954, 956, 958, 960, 962, 965, 967, 969, 971, 973, 975, 977, 980, 982, 984, 986, 988, 990, 992, 995, 997, 999, 1001, 1003, 1005, 1008, 1010, 1012, 1014, 1016, 1019, 1021, 1023, };
    return lut[y];
};
```

ということではないでしょうか？

なお、質問文の数式では値が元に戻らないため、数式を調べ直すことをお勧めします。私のコードが正しいとも限りません。

---

> どのようにべき乗計算をするか

についてですが、`x^y = 2^(y*log2(x))`の変換ができ、またCPUは２進数で処理しているため`2^x`や`log2(x)`には強いため高速化をもくろむことはできますが、結局は実数部が残り`<math.h>`を用いるかマクローリン展開などになります。誤差の問題もありますし、最初から`pow`を使用した方が高速なのではと思います。

なお、[x87プロセッサを使用した場合、`pow`はおおよそ次のように計算](https://sayurin.blogspot.jp/2008/12/pow-x-y.html)されます。

```
__declspec(noinline) double pow( double x, double y ){
  __asm{
    fld y
    fld x
    fyl2x
    fst ST(1)
    frndint
    fxch ST(1)
    fsub ST(0), ST(1)
    f2xm1
    fld1
    faddp ST(1), ST(0)
    fscale
  }
}
```

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。質問文に不備が多く、誠に申し訳ございません。私が体調を崩してしまい返答が遅れてしまいましたことも、重ねてお詫び申し上げます。指摘された通り、LUTを使ってMath.hを使用しない方法というのが正しい内容になります。教えていただいた内容をもとに内容を確認したいと思います。また、該当の内容は「精度 < 速度」を欲している場所であり、powよりはLUT等でという質問内容とでした。今まではpowで出していたのを、別の場所でpowを使った結果、遅延が発生した過去から、Math.hの使用禁止となった次第であります。上記、テイラー、マクローリン展開で実装する必要があるかもしれません。積分つらい・・・

Answer (score 0):

[Optimized pow() approximation](http://martin.ankerl.com/2007/10/04/optimized-pow-approximation-for-java-and-c-c/#Approximation_of_pow_in_C_and_C)のコードは如何でしょうか。

```
double fastPow(double a, double b) {
  union {
    double d;
    int x[2];
  } u = { a };
  u.x[1] = (int)(b * (u.x[1] - 1072632447) + 1072632447);
  u.x[0] = 0;
  return u.d;
}
```

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。早速確認してみたのですが、同じ計算式でfastPowを使ったときと通常のpowを使ったときで結果に差が出ています。Yに64を入れて計算した場合、3ほど差が開いてしまい、Yが大きければ大きいほど差分が発生するようで、fastPowをそのまま当てるのは難しそうです。

Comment: 一見さんかもしれないためコメントをするよりも更新しておきました。 @misoni112 さん、速度を上げれば制度が犠牲になるのは当然の結果です。精度が必要であればその旨を質問文に記載してください。

Comment: まことに申し訳ございません。今後は質問分に記載する内容を精査するようにいたします。